# How to send a float value using ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, floating-point, asihttprequest

I'm pretty new to iPhone. I want to send a request to a server with a float value for a specific key. Can anyone help me out here how to send a float value using ASIHTTPRequest in the request body. I tried changing the value to NSNumber and send it in body but the server response was an error invalid value type.

```
[_request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y] forKey:@"Y"];
```

Also, I can't send float directly as an NSObject.

Comment: What does your server side code look like?

Comment: nevermind i changed the server side code to accept strings.. Thanks for ur help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can convert your float value to nsstring and then send that value.

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",y];
[_request setPostValue:string forKey:@"Y"];
```

Comment: one question though the server is accepting request in float value will it effect..?

Comment: btw its not accepting that way either its still giving exception error. which is..


"(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError(\"invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''\",), <traceback object at 0x69a1cd63d50780e0>)";

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on your server, and you haven't described that to us at all.
I can guess that the server is probably expecting a string, not an NSNumber. Try changing the code to something more like this:

```
[_request setPostValue:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y] description] forKey:@"Y"];
```

This *might* print out the value as a string. (I haven't tested it.) If not, you'll need to use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html).